# Two i.i.d Rvs (Gaussian)

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

Q: You have two i.i.d Rv's X~N(0,1) Y~(0,1). Let Z=(X+Y)^2.

a) Find the mean on Z i.e E[Z}.

b) Find Corr(X,Z) & Corr(Y,Z).

c) Determine if Z & Y are uncorrelated.

Ans: Finding E[Z] was easy. 
I just did the E[(X+Y)^2] = E[X^2] + 2E[X]E[Y] + E[Y^2]. 
Where E[Y]=E[X]=0

and Var(X) = Var(Y) = 1 = E[X^2] = E[Y^2]

solving I got E[Z] = 2.

I am stuck on part B and C however. 
I know the Corr(X,Z) = E[XZ] = E[(X-E[X])(Z-E[Z])]
also E[XZ] = integral of XZ.fxz(x,z)dzdx for all values of z and x.

But I get stuck I am not given fxz(x,z). Specifically the variance of Z. If I know the variance of Z I can find E[XZ}. Any ideas??

Comment: Try plugging in $Z = (X+Y)^2 = X^2+2XY+Y^2$ for parts b) and c) and see where that takes you.

Comment: What do you mean? plug where? I see  in the E[XZ] formula right?

Comment: Into the part which you are stuck on. Specifically, $E[(X-E[X])(Z-E[Z])] = E[(X-0)(X^2+2XY+Y^2-2)]$.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. I was originally doing that but never considered pluging in Z

Comment: one last question. is E[XY^2]=E[X]E[Y^2]?

Comment: In general, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then so are $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ for any functions $f$ and $g$.